# Android Matching Phone Number Content Resolver w/ different formatting

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am looking at building a content resolver query which tries to do some phone number matching. It does not appear to be working when the phone number in the DB is stored w/ a different format as the one I am trying to compare to

eg. 
LocalContact Phone Number = '1 555 555 1234'
I am trying to compare with '+15555551234'

```
String phoneQueryString = "( mimetype = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2' 
                             AND (data1 = '+15555551234'  ))";

Cursor myContacts3 = myCR.query(
                    Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, 
                    phoneQueryString, 
                    null,
                    null);
```

myContacts3.getCount() returns zero records. I know I could use phoneNumberUtils to grab every phone number in the DB & PhoneNumberUtils.compare(num1,num2) but that is not efficient. I can strip out '+' from my '+15555551234', but then if it was reversed where my local contact was '+15555551234' and my source was '15555551234' it would not work.  basically I need to strip out any extra non-number chars in the query on data1. Or other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there is an undocumented sqlite function google added to the sqlite extern library:
static void phone_numbers_equal(sqlite3_context * context, int argc, sqlite3_value ** argv)

I have not used it for a while, but you should be able to use this:

```
String phoneQueryString = "( mimetype = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2' 
                             AND (phone_numbers_equal(data1,'+15555551234')  ))";

Cursor myContacts3 = myCR.query(
                    Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, 
                    phoneQueryString, 
                    null,
                    null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
String s = //your phone number goes here
s = s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

This should remove all characters that are not 0-9.  If you use that on both phone numbers their formats should match.

Comment: Yeah I can do that, I guess my issue is if the number as entered in android (data1) is '1 555 555 1234' then it won't match. Since the numbers can be entered any wishy washy way into the Data1 field, trying to figure out how to format that..

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ContactsContract.PhoneLookup](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html).

The format of the phone number does not matter. Comparison is robust and highly optimized on Android; it's done using a native sqlite function named PHONE_NUMBERS_EQUAL.

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode("+15555551234"));
Cursor phone =getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: This will work, for my issue though I was needing to return all the data from Data.CONTENT_URI. We had some additional data stored in the Data columns, and also pulling back if it was a primary / super-primary number..